# Scipy, optimize a function with argument dependent constraints

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to use negative of `scipy.optimize.minimize` to maximize a function `f (a, b, c, d)`. `d` is a `numpy.array` of guess variables.

I am trying to put some bounds on each `d`. And also a constraint on each `d` such that `(d1 * a1 + d2 * a2 + ... + d3 * a3) < some_Value` (`a` being the other argument to the subject function `f`).

My problem is how do I define this constraint as an argument to the maximize function.

I could not find any `maximize` function in the library so we're using the negative of `minimize` with `minimize` documentation over [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html).

Please consider asking for clarifications if the question is not clear enough.

Comment: Where are you getting `maximize` from? There's no maximize function in `scipy.optimize` (usually you would just minimize `-f(a, b, c, d)`).

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17025929/1461210) for an example showing constrained optimization using `scipy.optimize.minimize` with the SLSQP solver

Comment: That's exactly what I am doing, I forgot to mention that in the question. Please let me update the question.

Comment: @ali_m Thanks for your time but the problem I have is with creating a constraint which would take array of `x0` (`x0` is the internally passed set of variables) values and checks if sum all `x0 * a0` values satisfies some conditions. 
Please tell me if posting some code would help gettign a clearer picture of what I am asking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not totally clear from your description which of the parameters of `f` you are optimizing over. For the purposes of this example I'm going to use `x` to refer to the vector of parameters you are optimizing over, and `a` to refer to another parameter vector of the same length which is held constant.

Now let's suppose you wanted to enforce the following inequality constraint:

```
10 <= x[0] * a[0] + x[1] * a[1] + ... + x[n] * a[n]
```

First you must define a function that accepts `x` and `a` and returns a value that is non-negative when the constraint is met. In this case we could use:

```
lambda x, a: (x * a).sum() - 10
```

or equivalently:

```
lambda x, a: x.dot(a) - 10
```

Constraints are passed to minimize in a dict (or a sequence of dicts if you have multiple constraints to apply):

```
con = {'type': 'ineq',
       'fun': lambda x, a: a.dot(x) - 10,
       'jac': lambda x, a: a,
       'args': (a,)}
```

For greater efficiency I've also defined a function that returns the Jacobian (the sequence of partial derivatives of the constraint function w.r.t. each parameter in `x`), although this is not essential - if unspecified it will be estimated via first-order finite differences.

Your call to `minimize` would then look something like:

```
res = minimize(f, x0, args=(a,), method='SLSQP', constraints=con)
```

You can find another complete example of constrained optimization using SLSQP in the official documentation [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html#tutorial-sqlsp).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, this is almost exactly what I wanted to ask. A part of my original concern was that how will the `minimize` function know which values to pass to the constraint function `lambda x, a` along with `x` which is default, I assume. Is the parameter `a` to the lambda expression dependent on the order of items in the tuple passed as args (should `a` be the first item in the tuple, and hence the first argument of the objective function `f`?

Comment: The first argument to `f` (and to the jacobian, hessian and/or constraint function(s)) should always be the vector of parameters that `f` is being optimized over. Any additional parameters that are held constant should be passed via the `args` tuple in the order that they are needed by `f`. So if `f` is called as `f(x, a, b, c)` then you would call `minimize` with `args=(a, b, c)` and your constraint function would also need to accept `x, a, b, c` in that order.

Comment: My problem with this is that my constraints are evaluated in `f`. So, I have to run my model twice per iteration to feed scipy the constraints.