# How to use f2py to call a big fortran package

Tags: python, numpy, fortran, f2py

I need to use a math package which is entirely written in Fortran. The package is not in a single file but is compiled into an archive file (.a file).

I have the full source code. I don't know Fortran.

I did a quick read on f2py document here:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/f2py/

It just doesn't work for me. Are there any better documentation or guide for such problem?

**EDIT**

As requested in comments. I am not sure if I get it correctly (I don't know Fortran), there is some function that probably useful for me:

```
  SUBROUTINE QP_initialize( data, control, inform )
  TYPE ( QP_data_type ), INTENT( INOUT ) :: data
  TYPE ( QP_control_type ), INTENT( OUT ) :: control
  TYPE ( QP_inform_type ), INTENT( OUT ) :: inform

  SUBROUTINE QP_solve( prob, data, control, inform, C_stat, B_stat )
  TYPE ( QPT_problem_type ), INTENT( INOUT ) :: prob
  TYPE ( QP_data_type ), INTENT( INOUT ) :: data
  TYPE ( QP_control_type ), INTENT( IN ) :: control
  TYPE ( QP_inform_type ), INTENT( OUT ) :: inform
  INTEGER, INTENT( OUT ), OPTIONAL, DIMENSION( prob%m ) :: C_stat
  INTEGER, INTENT( OUT ), OPTIONAL, DIMENSION( prob%n ) :: B_stat
```

Comment: How many Fortran functions do you need to call, and can you give us one or two examples including their argument lists?

Comment: @JohnZwinck I don't know. Possibly around 3-5 in production. I need to try different algorithms to see which one works for me. But the code that I can freely find on the Internet are all written in fortran.

Comment: I think in practice, there should be some way to automatically extract the prototype (signature?) from the fortran code and then I can simply link those object file into a shared library. Finally, I call the shared library using the prototype in python?

Comment: Yes, that's not too far off.  However, can you give us one or two examples including their argument lists?  There is a big difference between calling functions that expect an int vs a string vs an array....

Comment: I am not sure if I get it correctly. I get one that is probably useful for me:
       SUBROUTINE QP_initialize( data, control, inform )
     TYPE ( QP_data_type ), INTENT( INOUT ) :: data
      TYPE ( QP_control_type ), INTENT( OUT ) :: control
      TYPE ( QP_inform_type ), INTENT( OUT ) :: inform

Comment: Please add that additional information to the question instead of putting it in the comments.

Comment: some kind of data structure like in C and make the problem more difficult?

Comment: OK. I added the information to the question

Comment: So you're using the Galahad library, right? http://www.galahad.rl.ac.uk/doc/qp.pdf  See this question for another user trying to do QP in Python: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17009774/quadratic-program-qp-solver-that-only-depends-on-numpy-scipy

Comment: Yes. I also know the existence of our library, but I want to test if Galahad performance is better or not.

Answer (score 0):

Since you say you only need to call 3-5 different functions, one easy way is to use `ctypes`.  It's included with Python, and while at first glance it appears to be made for calling C functions, on many systems Fortran is compatible with C for the most part.

See here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html

Alternatively, you may be able to use SciPy to do your quadratic program optimization: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html

Comment: I am not sure how ctypes will help to pass the Fortran derived types here. At least I see no advantage with regards to f2py.